# How to extract and keep data from a SQLite Query?

Tags: sqlite

I have a relational DB with some related vertical tables.

I have already write a query that give me the result that I am looking for. The result is presented in the column "Result_Total", and every row in this column is the multiplication between column "Quantity of Material" and Column "Quantity of Part" (for the same rows).

At the end, I only need two things:

1. to keep and save in a table the column "3000:DeviceID" (which is the ID of a Device), "Material ID" (which is the ID of a Material related to the Device) and "Result_Total"  (which is a number that says how much material is presented in the device). (to keep the table as show in the figure)
2. for sames devices I have several materials. So I need to find per Device, the amount of material, This is:

to sum all the values of the column Results, that have the same ID of material, for the same ID of Device. (the small table in the picture)

I think this can be made in the same query but I have tried to make a query inside of the query and I couldn´t

The result of the query is the following: (I have hided the columns that are not necessary)

and the table below of the big one is what I need to have (notice that result sums the same category for material ID for the same category for Device).

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the suggestion. I was not familiar with. The firs problem I solved by using: CREATE TABLE tablename AS (myquery); That, creates a table with the results of the query. Then using group by I use:  SELECT
    "Device ID",
    "Material ID",
    SUM(Result_Total)  Quantity
FROM
     RESULTADOS
GROUP BY
    "Material ID";    but it seems that some values are out of the query.

Comment: Maybe is better if I re-edit the question only for this part about the GROUP BY. What do you think @Shawn

Comment: You'll want to join on both device id and material id to get the right numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the guidance of Shawn, I come up with the solution.

**1. TO KEEP THE QUERY RESULTS IN A TABLE:** Just write before the query: **CREATE TABLE TableNameResultsQuery AS**

```
create table "3000Devices2" as select * from "3000Devices";
create table "3000DevicesExchanges2" as select * from "3000DevicesExchanges";
CREATE table RESULTADOS as
SELECT
    "3000DevicesExchanges"."3000:DeviceID" as "Device ID",
    .
    .
    "3000Devices".Name as "Device Name" 
FROM
    "3000DevicesExchanges"
    INNER JOIN
        "3000Devices" on "3000Devices".ID = "3000DevicesExchanges"."3000:DeviceID"
    .
    .
    .   
    INNER JOIN
      "0000Materials" on "0000Materials".ID = "1000PartsComposition"."0000:Material"
WHERE  "3000DevicesExchanges"."3000:Devices" is not null;
DROP TABLE "3000Devices2";
DROP TABLE "3000DevicesExchanges2";
```

2. **To Manage the information** of that query (table) I used **GROUP BY**:

> ```
> SELECT
>     "Device ID",
>     "Device Name",
>     "Material ID",
>     "Material Name",
>     SUM(Result_Total)  Quantity
> FROM
>      RESULTADOS
> GROUP BY
>   "Device ID", "Material ID";
> ```

**3. To export the results of the query to CSV:**

```
sqlite> .open databasename.db
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output filename.csv
sqlite> select * from tbl1; (make it the query)
sqlite> .output stdout
```

Thanks a lot